# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match, when using Rinat package in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using the Rinat API to extract the observations submitted by a list of users to the iNaturalist app. The API function I'm using is as below, which is taken from GitHub (https://github.com/ropensci/rinat/blob/master/R/get_inat_obs_user.R):

```
get_inat_obs_user <- function(username, maxresults = 10000){
  
  # check Internet connection
  if (!curl::has_internet()) {
    message("No Internet connection.")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  
  base_url <- "http://www.inaturalist.org/"
  # check that iNat can be reached
  if (httr::http_error(base_url)) { # TRUE: 400 or above
    message("iNaturalist API is unavailable.")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  
  q_path <- paste0(username, ".csv")
  ping_path <- paste0(username, ".json")
  
  ping_query <- "&per_page=1&page=1"
  ### Make the first ping to the server to get the number of results
  ### easier to pull down if you make the query in json, but easier to arrange results
  ### that come down in CSV format
  ping <-  GET(base_url, path = paste0("observations/", ping_path), query = ping_query)
  total_res <- as.numeric(ping$headers$`x-total-entries`)
  
  if(total_res == 0){
    stop("Your search returned zero results. Perhaps your user does not exist.")
  }
  page_query <-"&per_page=200&page=1"
  dat <-  GET(base_url, path = paste0("observations/", q_path), query = page_query)
  data_out <- read.csv(textConnection(content(dat, as = "text")))
  if(maxresults > 200){
    for(i in 2:ceiling(total_res/200)){
      page_query <- paste0("&per_page=200&page=", i)
      dat <-  GET(base_url, path = paste0("observations/", q_path), query = page_query)
      data_out <- rbind(data_out, read.csv(textConnection(content(dat, as = "text"))))
    }
    
  }
  
  if(maxresults < dim(data_out)[1]){
    data_out <- data_out[1:maxresults,]
  }
  
  return(data_out)
}
```

I'm also using a for loop to iterate the API function through a list of usernames (in below sample data):

```
usernames<-

    user_login
1   a_random_kaiser
2   a_wade
3   achaas33
4   adam247
5   adam294
6   ailsa2
7   anne278
8   anne370
9   apwiemer
10  arbw
11  aslan1758
12  asmalley
13  aspinwall
14  atypicalhermit
15  aurora143
16  autumn307
17  avenkal
18  awburck
19  badbotanist
20  baleinenature
21  barich
22  batesfire
23  beavers
24  becca57
25  beesis
26  beetlequeenrs
27  ben543
28  ben566
29  bethanyk63
30  betty108
31  boatbirder
32  bobbyboy
33  bobkat
34  brad131987
35  bradders100
36  cadds
37  caketea86
38  carluk
39  carolina711
40  cleo2211
41  cobydo
42  cocothecat
```

**EDIT**

```
sequence <- seq_along(usernames)  
User_obs_global <- data.frame()  

for (var in sequence){
  User_obs <- get_inat_obs_user(as.character(
    User_no_obs_Oxfordshire$user_login[var])) 
  
  User_obs_global <- rbind(User_obs_global, User_obs)
}
```

```
sequence = 1:nrow(usernames)
for (var in sequence)
  {User_obs<- get_inat_obs_user(as.character(username$user_login[var]))}
```

However, I keep getting the below error:

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :  numbers of columns of arguments
> do not match

I tried searching previous Stack Overflow posts related to this error, and understand this could be due to mismatch in number of columns between successive username records. Nevertheless, the number of columns should be the same for all username records, since their source is the same. Hence, I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my code.

I can run the API function successfully for individual usernames by the way, but I have a few thousand usernames to loop through.

Comment: Please share more data. Use `seq_along(x)` instead of `1:nrow(x)`. You have not defined the variable `User_obs`. Do this outside the loop. Probably, your are missing at least one index, e.g. `User_obs[i]` if this is e.g. a vector and you are aiming to assign...

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using #install.packages("rinat") and #library(rinat) to perform the get_inat_obs_user function. The usernames variable defined above is actually a CSV that contains the full version of the above sample data with the same columns. I tried revising my code to the below, but think something still needs to be fixed: 
```sequence = seq_along(usernames)```
```User_obs_global <- data.frame()``` 
```for (var in sequence) 
{User_obs <- get_inat_obs_user(as.character(usernames$user_login[var])) 
User_obs_global <- rbind(User_obs_global, User_obs)}```

Comment: Again, `User_obs` is not defined outside the loop. I think you want to index ...., e.g. `User_obs[i]`. Why `User_obs_global ` needs to be a dataframe instead of a vector `c()` or a `list()`?

Comment: Sorry do you mean define the variable User_obs outside the loop as in the below:

```User_obs <- data.frame()```
```for (var in sequence) {User_obs <- get_inat_obs_user(as.character(usernames$user_login[var]))```

Comment: The output User_obs_global will consist of many columns representing different parameters of users' observations(e.g. time, date, species, location), hence I defined as dataframe vs. vector/list. Each user's observations will also consist of many rows of records, and the output will consist of these multiple rows of records per user, which are bound across multiple users; hence was wondering what should be the best way to apply index ```User_obs[i] ``` in this case too.

Comment: @user438383, thanks for the edit. It works, except that the output I'm getting only contains results for the first 3 usernames instead of the full list of usernames. I'm wondering if this might be due to any set limit that I need to increase?

Comment: I tried playing around with the below in the API function itself, but just get different numbers of duplicated records across the first 3 usernames:
```function(username, maxresults = 10000)```
```if(maxresults > 200){
    for(i in 2:ceiling(total_res/200)){
      page_query <- paste0("&per_page=200&page=", i)
      dat <-  GET(base_url, path = paste0("observations/", q_path), query = page_query)
      data_out <- rbind(data_out, read.csv(textConnection(content(dat, as = "text"))))
    }```

As these codes are way beyond my present R skills, would be grateful for any help from anyone.